# How To Resend Email With The Email Address Listed in Your Google Forms?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, gmail

I'm having hard time to use this command
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAdd,"thanks","",);

I would like to resend my preformatted emails to the email address on my google form.
Here is my code

```
enter code here

function sendEmails2() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var startRow = 2;
 var startCol = 1
 var numRows = 500;
 var numCols = 20
 var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow,startCol,numRows,numCols);
 var data =dataRange.getValues();

 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i){
  var row = data[0]
  var row1 = data[0]
  var timeStamp = row[1];
  var name = row[2];
  var emailAdd = row[3];
  var age = row[4];
  var phoneNum = row[5];
  var yesNo = row[6];
  var currentDate = row1[9];
  var timeDiff = currentDate - timeStamp
  var msgDay1 = row1[11]
  var msgDay2 = row1[12]
  var msgDay3 = row1[13]
  var msgDay4 = row1[11]
}
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAdd,"thanks","",);
//This code below was used to get the Body of the message in terms of HTML
//My goal is to resend my preformatted email to the email address on my google forms
//How can I attached the HTML using the GmailApp.sendEmail command?
//I want them to receive the exact preformatted email that I made.
/*  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Sun Life");
var threads = label.getThreads();

for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++){
 var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++){
  var msg = messages[j].getBody();
  var sub = messages[j].getSubject();
  var dat = messages[j].getDate();
  var sheetDebugOut = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheetDebugOut.appendRow([msg, sub, dat])
}
  //threads[i].removeLabel(label);
}*/
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This `var row = data[0]` should  probably be `var row = data[i]`

This `var row1 = data[0]` should probably be `var row1 = row[0]`

GmailApp.sendEmail() should be inside the loop

You are missing your optional parameters in the sendEmail method

fix those and see if that helps

Comment: Thanks for the help, I forgot to use the index and also to put the sendEmail method inside the loop. I tried using .forward(email_add) since I will just resend my preformatted email.